# confusion that a relation is a function or a set?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In the appendix of Hoffman Kunze's Linear Algebra book , a relation is defined as a $\textbf{function}$ that maps each pair $(x,y) \in X \times X$  to the set $ \{0,1\}$. If the relation holds then $R_x = 1$ , otherwise $R_x=0$. This definition is very logical to me ,but in some higher level texts such as Royden's Real Analysis or Dudley's Real Analysis and Probability, a relation is defined as a $\textbf{set}$. Why do they differ in defining a relation and make the readers confused?

Comment: That is not just *a* function, it's a **predicate**. A binary relation on $X$ is a subset of the Cartesian product $X \times X$. A subset of a set can be obtained by using a predicate to filter out elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are often multiple ways to define essentially the same object.  That's something you'll have to get used to.

The traditional way to define functions is to say that they're a special kind of relation.  If you want to define relations in terms of functions, then you'll need to define functions as sets first and then use the relations-as-functions definition, at least assuming that, like nearly everyone, you're using set theory for foundations.